# How to determine what is using majority of physical memory?

Tags: linux, memory

I have Linux machine with 32GB RAM. According to top, only 9.264 GB is free

```
GiB Mem :   31.423 total,    9.264 free,   20.670 used,    1.490 buff/cache
GiB Swap:    1.076 total,    1.076 free,    0.000 used.   10.543 avail Mem
```

but the process list in top only adds up to 102.1 MB for RES and 3251.6 MB for VIRT.

How can I determine what is using the rest of memory?

Here are few other memory checks:

```
vmstat 1 5
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0      0 9714504 179376 1382620    0    0     3    19   34   37  4  1 95  0  0
 0  0      0 9714400 179376 1382652    0    0     0     0   42   80  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0 9714400 179376 1382652    0    0     0     0   48   89  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0 9714400 179376 1382652    0    0     0     0   37   72  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0 9714400 179376 1382652    0    0     0     0   36   63  0  0 100  0  0



cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       32949560 kB
MemFree:         9714532 kB
Buffers:          179376 kB
Cached:          1311020 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          1078684 kB
Inactive:         457080 kB
Active(anon):      46016 kB
Inactive(anon):     8356 kB
Active(file):    1032668 kB
Inactive(file):   448724 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       1128444 kB
SwapFree:        1128444 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         45416 kB
Mapped:            30660 kB
Shmem:              9008 kB
Slab:              71632 kB
SReclaimable:      57932 kB
SUnreclaim:        13700 kB
KernelStack:         848 kB
PageTables:         3548 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    17603224 kB
Committed_AS:     318636 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      197832 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359533592 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:      4096 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       44992 kB
DirectMap2M:    33509376 kB
```

**Update**
slabtop reports:

```
 Active / Total Objects (% used)    : 253008 / 257418 (98.3%)
 Active / Total Slabs (% used)      : 8361 / 8361 (100.0%)
 Active / Total Caches (% used)     : 70 / 99 (70.7%)
 Active / Total Size (% used)       : 62949.41K / 64953.55K (96.9%)
 Minimum / Average / Maximum Object : 0.01K / 0.25K / 16.12K

  OBJS ACTIVE  USE OBJ SIZE  SLABS OBJ/SLAB CACHE SIZE NAME
 67314  67314 100%    0.10K   1726       39      6904K buffer_head
 40131  39973  99%    0.19K   1911       21      7644K dentry
 26316  26316 100%    0.11K    731       36      2924K sysfs_dir_cache
 22432  22432 100%    0.96K   1402       16     22432K ext4_inode_cache
 11456  11456 100%    0.06K    179       64       716K kmalloc-64
  9180   9180 100%    0.04K     90      102       360K ext4_extent_status
  8848   8284  93%    0.57K    316       28      5056K inode_cache
  8463   7478  88%    0.19K    403       21      1612K kmalloc-192
  6944   6944 100%    0.07K    124       56       496K Acpi-ParseExt
  6784   6457  95%    0.03K     53      128       212K kmalloc-32
  6144   6144 100%    0.01K     12      512        48K kmalloc-8
  5292   5198  98%    0.55K    189       28      3024K radix_tree_node
  5120   5120 100%    0.02K     20      256        80K kmalloc-16
  3864   3232  83%    0.07K     69       56       276K anon_vma
  3774   3774 100%    0.04K     37      102       148K Acpi-Namespace
  3488   2866  82%    0.25K    218       16       872K kmalloc-256
  2635   2635 100%    0.05K     31       85       124K shared_policy_node
  2048   1681  82%    0.12K     64       32       256K kmalloc-128
  1806   1806 100%    0.09K     43       42       172K kmalloc-96
  1248   1109  88%    0.50K     78       16       624K kmalloc-512
  1200   1160  96%    0.63K     48       25       768K proc_inode_cache
  1200   1200 100%    0.66K     50       24       800K shmem_inode_cache
  1152   1101  95%    1.00K     72       16      1152K kmalloc-1024
  1152   1152 100%    0.11K     32       36       128K jbd2_journal_head
   570    443  77%    0.81K     30       19       480K task_xstate
   512    512 100%    0.03K      4      128        16K jbd2_revoke_record_s
   480    397  82%    6.00K     96        5      3072K task_struct
   475    475 100%    0.62K     19       25       304K sock_inode_cache
   448    350  78%    2.00K     28       16       896K kmalloc-2048
   420    314  74%    1.06K     14       30       448K signal_cache
   378    378 100%    0.38K     18       21       144K blkdev_requests
   357    357 100%    0.08K      7       51        28K Acpi-State
   351    351 100%    0.10K      9       39        36K blkdev_ioc
   340    340 100%    0.05K      4       85        16K jbd2_journal_handle
   320    320 100%    0.06K      5       64        20K kmem_cache_node
   320    320 100%    0.06K      5       64        20K ext4_free_data
   300    300 100%    0.13K     10       30        40K ext4_allocation_context
   270    270 100%    1.75K     15       18       480K TCP
   256    256 100%    0.02K      1      256         4K jbd2_revoke_table_s
   224    224 100%    0.07K      4       56        16K ext4_io_end
   219    219 100%    0.05K      3       73        12K ip_fib_trie
   210    210 100%    2.06K     14       15       448K sighand_cache
   204    204 100%    0.12K      6       34        24K fsnotify_event
   195    195 100%    2.06K     13       15       416K idr_layer_cache
   187    187 100%    0.94K     11       17       176K UNIX
   184    184 100%    0.09K      4       46        16K fscache_cookie_jar
   175    175 100%    0.31K      7       25        56K mnt_cache
   170    170 100%    0.02K      1      170         4K numa_policy
   152    138  90%    4.00K     19        8       608K kmalloc-4096
   150    150 100%    0.62K      6       25        96K files_cache
   144    144 100%    0.25K      9       16        36K kmem_cache
   120    120 100%    1.06K      4       30       128K UDPv6
   112    112 100%    1.94K      7       16       224K TCPv6
   110    110 100%    0.73K      5       22        80K cifs_inode_cache
   108    108 100%    0.88K      6       18        96K mm_struct
   100    100 100%    0.16K      4       25        16K sigqueue
    96     96 100%    0.32K      4       24        32K taskstats
    96     96 100%    0.25K      6       16        24K dquot
    90     90 100%    0.44K      5       18        40K xfrm_dst_cache
    84     84 100%    2.21K      6       14       192K blkdev_queue
    76     76 100%    0.81K      4       19        64K bdev_cache
    72     72 100%    0.88K      4       18        64K UDP
```

**Update 2**

Output of `smem -R 32G -w`

```
Area                           Used      Cache   Noncache
firmware/hardware            605196          0     605196
kernel image                      0          0          0
kernel dynamic memory      24459656    2776744   21682912
userspace memory              73964      22308      51656
free memory                 8415616    8415616          0
```

Comment: The output of `ps aux`  command contains `RSS` field that shows resident set size, the non-swapped physical memory that a task has used (in kilobytes) and  `VSIZE` field that shows virtual memory size of the process. You can aslo use `top` command that has the `RES` and `VIRT` fields.

Comment: Or simply with `free -h` :-)

Comment: Thanks, @YuriGinsburg & @hedgie. I already used `top` and found the `RES` and `VIRT` values as reported in my OP. I looked at the output of `ps aux` but total `RSS` and `VSIZE` are reporting nearly the same as top's `RES` and `VIRT` as noted in my OP. `free -h` lines up with `top` header information. Unfortunately, none of these commands are indicating what is using over 70% of my memory.

Comment: what does slabtop report? Is there some sort of huge kernel-memory usage?

Comment: @stoney - slabtop report added to OP

Comment: `grep . /proc/[0-9]*/statm | sort -rnk2,2 | head` gives you a list of the memory hogs. You can also sum up the second column (rss) with `.. | awk '{t+=$2}END{print t}'`.

Comment: The only other tool that comes to mind is `smem -R 32G -w` which sums up the memory usage. stuff under firmware/hardware shows the memory used by hardware plus the kernel memory.

Comment: @stoney -Thanks. I've added output for `smem` to the OP. Could you please take a look and let me know your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try running
`ps aux --sort -rss` as root.

I have different outputs when I do `ps aux --sort -rss | wc -l` than when I do when I'm running as root.

Further... this command I found helpful.

```
ps -eo size,pid,user,command --sort -size | \
    awk '{ hr=$1/1024 ; printf("%13.2f Mb ",hr) } { for ( x=4 ; x<=NF ; x++ ) { printf("%s ",$x) } print "" }' |\
    cut -d "" -f2 | cut -d "-" -f1
```

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44711589

Comment: Thanks. I've already tried `ps` but `RSS` show essentially the same as `RES` in top. Please see my comment above. I tried the other command you referenced which I think is just stripping out the `VSZ` field only with some formatting. `VSZ` adds up to more than my physical memory which is expected since it's represents virtual. I'm only interested in physical memory allocation.

Comment: Check this script. It returns the actual memory being utilized, by using `pmap` it returns the total based on each process. Where `ps` identifies all the `pid` running `pmap -x <pid>` returns the reserved space and utilization. This guy put together a script to run it against all the processes identified in the `ps` 
https://github.com/shovon8/sysmon

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have any filesystem created on RAM

Do a df -TPh, check  tmpfs,ramfs.. usually are the RAM FS, check the usage for those FS in case you have any

Example:

```
# df -TPh
tmpfs          tmpfs     512M  256M  256M  50% /mnt/ramdisk
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
```

Comment: Thanks. I have 4 types devtempfs, tmpfs, ext4 & cifs. There are 6 filesystems of type tmpfs. However, only one has non-zero used space. It shows 8.9M used. So unfortunately, I don't think this is the issue.